# Hay Day diamond buying list

Tags: hay-day

Is there a page/wiki shows each items in the game (Hay Day) cost how many diamonds? I am currently trying to figure out the requested items in boat order list worth how many diamonds.

Answer (score 2):

#### List of Cost in Diamonds of completed products (Alphabetical):

#### Crops:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Production</kbd><kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Chili Pepper</kbd><kbd>4 Hours</kbd>   <kbd>7</kbd>       
<kbd>Cotton</kbd>      <kbd>2.5 Hours</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>       
<kbd>Soybean</kbd>     <kbd>20 Minutes</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>       
<kbd>Sugar Cane</kbd>  <kbd>30 Minutes</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>       
<kbd>Tomato</kbd>      <kbd>6 Hours</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>

#### Expansion Items:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Land Deed</kbd>   <kbd>12</kbd>      
<kbd>Mallet</kbd>      <kbd>12</kbd>      
<kbd>Marker Stick</kbd><kbd>12</kbd>

#### Feed:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Production</kbd><kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Chicken Feed</kbd><kbd>5 Minutes</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>       
<kbd>Cow Feed</kbd>    <kbd>10 Minutes</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

#### Fishing:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Production</kbd><kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Blue Lure</kbd>   <kbd>1 Hour</kbd>    <kbd>34</kbd>      
<kbd>Gold Lure</kbd>   <kbd>30 Minutes</kbd><kbd>83</kbd>      
<kbd>Green Lure</kbd>  <kbd>1.25 Hours</kbd><kbd>19</kbd>      
<kbd>Purple Lure</kbd> <kbd>45 Minutes</kbd><kbd>53</kbd>      
<kbd>Red Lure</kbd>    <kbd>1.5 Hours</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd>

#### Upgrade Items:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Bolt</kbd>        <kbd>8</kbd>       
<kbd>Duct Tape</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>       
<kbd>Nail</kbd>        <kbd>8</kbd>       
<kbd>Plank</kbd>       <kbd>8</kbd>       
<kbd>Screw</kbd>       <kbd>8</kbd>       
<kbd>Wood Panel</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>

#### Utility Items:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Axe</kbd>         <kbd>4</kbd>       
<kbd>Dynamite</kbd>    <kbd>3</kbd>       
<kbd>Saw</kbd>         <kbd>5</kbd>       
<kbd>Shovel</kbd>      <kbd>10</kbd>      
<kbd>TNT Barrel</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>

#### Other Products:

**<kbd>Item Name</kbd>   <kbd>Production</kbd><kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Brown Sugar</kbd> <kbd>20 Minutes</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>       
<kbd>Cheese</kbd>      <kbd>1 Hour</kbd>    <kbd>22</kbd>      
<kbd>Cherry Juice</kbd><kbd>2.5 Hours</kbd> <kbd>40</kbd>      
<kbd>Fish Fillet</kbd> <kbd>2 Hours</kbd>   <kbd>11</kbd>      
<kbd>Syrup</kbd>       <kbd>1.5 Hours</kbd> <kbd>17</kbd>

#### Other Services:

**<kbd>Service Name</kbd>   <kbd>Diamonds</kbd>**

<kbd>Get Boat Now</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>       
<kbd>Publish Advert</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>       
<kbd>Remove Advert</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>

*Note: I am going to keep updating this list as I go, since it has been a long time and no answer, I might as well start an attempt.

Comment: you can regard fish fillet as a 2-hour item, since it is that long to the fastest fishing spot to respawn.

Answer (score 0):

Since HowlinWulf already posted the tables and they are correct, I am derailing the question a bit in order to discuss strategy.

---

The most efficient way of using diamonds to complete boat orders (if you have some (6 or more) hours left on the boat, is to **hire Tom.** ([wiki article on Tom](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Tom))

For **15 diamonds** a day, Tom can get you **up to 108 items** of almost any kind, including saws, shovels, dinamyte, EXCEPT building materials (deed, screws, planks, etc).

[YMMV](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YMMV) because you won't be up every two hours of the whole day like a cuckoo clock. But it will still be less than **half diamond per item** even if you only visit the farm four times in those 24 hours. You can refuse his search if the large order is not nine items and he will rest for two minutes, then be ready again. The full two hours waiting is only after you buy something from Tom.

**All** the boat order's requested **items** can be obtained **via Tom**. Ask for help on the ones with high quantity, send Tom to fetch the rarer ones.

in the 4 hours delay between boats, you can send Tom in advance twice to prep the next order.

Also, the cost of using tom can drop to lower than 0.1 diamond per item if you hire him for 10 days, even lower if you get him with the discount baloon. (it can reach a minimum of 0.083 diamond per item, [if you give up your real world life for 10 days](http://www.olganon.org/) - *ProTip: don't*).